# Devleoping Adobe AIR Application for Android Using HTML

Tags: android, html, air

Can we develop Adobe AIR 2.5 application for Android 2.2 using initialwindow content as a html file

?What I wanted to know was whether we can use HTML content for android phones..The documentation says no..is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AIR's stageWebView to render HTML.